# Drivers installation

Tags: drivers, system-installation, asus

A few months ago I decided to change my old computer with Windows XP OS for a new rebuild. Having assembled a new box with an Asus Maximus V11 Hero, an i7-4770K, and Sapphire R9 280X. I have loaded Ubuntu 14.10  64bit from an LXF CD and updated from the net. I have a problem trying to load the MB drivers. From the MB CD I get "Please update to the latest Linux Kernel for motherboard chip set and components support" I do not want to Load Windows XP on to a separate partition. Info on how to proceed will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks, Robert.

Comment: "From the MB CD I get " Why would you need that? We use generic drivers so the Ubuntu install will sort your drivers out by itself where the general rule is: "if supported it works". "LXF CD"? A random download?  "Please update to the latest Linux Kernel for motherboard chipset and components support" That disk probably does not support Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu you don't need to install 'separate' drivers from manufacturer CDs. Most drivers are already built in the system. Those discs you are mentioning probably designed for Windows and provide some necessary or additional features for the motherboard to work under Windows. But in Ubuntu these features are usually provided by default. So may not bother installing any special drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Your manufacturers CD typically won't have drivers for Linux (Ubuntu or any other distribution for that matter) Don't worry about that. As Rinzwind points out the kernel supplies support for the main-board components (in most cases). I've never needed specific drivers for any main-board I've purchased whether it by Asus or Gigabyte or ??????

You can update your installation to the latest kernel either with Software Updater in the GUI or via the command line (my personal favorite) by opening a terminal and issuing the commands: 
`sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Occasionally wireless or graphics drivers are needed but usually everything works out of the box...